# Parsing Complex XML in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I'm new to Stackoverflow, so I am getting to grips with the way this works! :)

I am writing a program which requires me to parse some XML files, however I am encountering difficulties as the file is quite complex.

Tried using DOM, any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<REPORT xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <REPORT_HEADER statement_id="4" registered_currency="EUR" run_type="INDIC" publication_timestamp="2019-01-21T22:44:36+00:00" publication_date="2019-01-21" settlement_date="2019-01-20" market_name="B" participant_name="PT" report_type="SS"/>
    <REPORT_SUMMARY>
        <CHARGE_SUMMARY amount="0.0000" date="2019-01-20" name="CPREMIUM"/>
        <CHARGE_SUMMARY amount="-3.8895" date="2019-01-20" name="CUNIMB"/>
    </REPORT_SUMMARY>
    <REPORT_DETAIL>
        <RESOURCE name="GU">
            <CHARGE name="CAB">
                <VALUE amount="3.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T00:30:00+00:00"/>
                <VALUE amount="0.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T01:30:00+00:00"/>
            </CHARGE>
            <CHARGE name="CPO">
                <VALUE amount="0.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T00:30:00+00:00"/>
                <VALUE amount="0.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T01:30:00+00:00"/>
            </CHARGE>
        </RESOURCE>
        <RESOURCE name="PU">
            <CHARGE name="COD">
                <VALUE amount="0.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T00:30:00+00:00"/>
                <VALUE amount="0.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T01:30:00+00:00"/>
            </CHARGE>
            <CHARGE name="MOD">
                <VALUE amount="1.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T00:30:00+00:00"/>
                <VALUE amount="2.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T01:30:00+00:00"/>
            </CHARGE>
        </RESOURCE>
    </REPORT_DETAIL>
</REPORT>
```

Required output, which I am aiming for.

```
CHARGE_SUMMARY amount="0.0000" date="2019-01-20" name="CPREMIUM"
CHARGE_SUMMARY amount="-3.8895" date="2019-01-20" name="CUNIMB"

RESOURCE name="GU" CHARGE name="CAB" amount="3.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T00:30:00+00:00"
RESOURCE name="GU" CHARGE name="CAB" amount="0.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T01:30:00+00:00"
RESOURCE name="GU" CHARGE name="CPO" amount="0.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T00:30:00+00:00"
RESOURCE name="GU" CHARGE name="CPO" amount="0.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T01:30:00+00:00"

RESOURCE name="PU" CHARGE name="COD  VALUE amount="0.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T00:30:00+00:00"
RESOURCE name="PU" CHARGE name="COD  VALUE amount="0.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T01:30:00+00:00"
RESOURCE name="PU" CHARGE name="MOD" VALUE amount="1.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T00:30:00+00:00"
RESOURCE name="PU" CHARGE name="MOD" VALUE amount="2.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T00:30:00+00:00"
```

I am able to parse through the CHARGE_SUMMARY using DOM, see below

```
 package Project;

 import java.io.File;
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
 import org.w3c.dom.Document;
 import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
 import org.w3c.dom.Node;
 import org.w3c.dom.Element;

 import java.util.*; // Required for Hashmap


 public class Parse_File_SS{

 public HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> parsing_SS(String path , String report_type){

    String path_location = path;
 System.out.println("Parsing SS: " + "String: "+ path_location);

 String report = report_type;
 System.out.println("Report type: "+ report);

 HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> hm=new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();  

 try {
 File inputFile = new File(path_location);
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
 Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
 doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
 //[GETTING ROOT ELEMENT]
 System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
  NodeList nList1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("CHARGE_SUMMARY");
   //Iterating through CHARGE_SUMMARY List, within REPORT_SUMMARY******************************************************************
      for (int temp = 0; temp < nList1.getLength(); temp++) {
                        Node nNode = nList1.item(temp);
                        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

                        //Get Values Associated with Charge Summary

                        //1. amount
                        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                            System.out.println("amount : " 
                               + eElement.getAttribute("amount"));
                        }
                        //2. date
                        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                            System.out.println("date : " 
                               + eElement.getAttribute("date"));
                        }
                        //3. name
                        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                            System.out.println("name : " 
                               + eElement.getAttribute("name"));
                        }
      } //
```

However below is where I encounter the problem, by using
 NodeList nList3 = doc.getElementsByTagName("CHARGE"); I am iterating through all the Charges & not the specific charges required

```
  //**********[GETTING TAGNAME: REPORT_DETAIL]******************************************************************           
   NodeList nList3 = doc.getElementsByTagName("CHARGE");
   System.out.println("-----------CHARGE-----------------");         


        //We need to iterate through the CHARGE within RESOURCE within REPORT_DETAIL******************************************************
        for (int temp3 = 0; temp3 < nList3.getLength(); temp3++) {  

                 Node nNode3 = nList3.item(temp3);
                 System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode3.getNodeName());
            if (nNode3.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement3 = (Element) nNode3;
                    System.out.println("name : "  + eElement3.getAttribute("name"));


              //**** If  [1]  CHARGE_SUMMARY  name = CAB   ********************************************************************************                      
                          // now if name = CAB iterate through the values

                            if(eElement3.getAttribute("name").contains("CAB")) { 
                                System.out.println("CAB is Present");

                          //**********[GETTING TAGNAME: VALUE]**************************************************************    
                               NodeList nList_CAB = doc.getElementsByTagName("CAB");   //Get the list of values                                
                               System.out.println("The Length of the list is CAB: "+nList_CAB.getLength());
```

The length of the list is zero which is a problem,

```
                           //Now iterate through them
                                         for (int temp_CAB = 0; temp_CAB < nList_CAB.getLength(); temp_CAB++) {
                                                Node nNode_CAB = nList_CAB.item(temp_CAB);
                                                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element of values:" + nNode_CAB.getNodeName()); 

                                          //1. date time
                                            if (nNode_CAB.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                                                    Element eElement_CAB = (Element) nNode_CAB;
                                                    System.out.println("datetime : "  + eElement_CAB.getAttribute("datetime"));
                                            }
                                          //2. amount
                                            if (nNode_CAB.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                                                    Element eElement_CAB = (Element) nNode_CAB;
                                                    System.out.println("amount : " + eElement_CAB.getAttribute("amount"));

                                             }
                                           }   
                                       }               
                }    
  }

    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();

    }       
       return hm;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your expected output and what have you tried already?

Comment: Please, be more specific about what you are expecting to get and provide a fragment of your code used to parse the XML, so the users may have the context of the question.

Comment: I would recommend looking into [jaxb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding).

Comment: The `<RESOURCE>` tags aren't closed.

Comment: I have updated the above to detail, the xml file, the goal output & the code

Comment: For parsing such complex XML document I suggest you to use DSM library.   mfatihercik.github.io/dsm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use XPath for this, as I think it makes the intention more clear:

```
public static void main(String... args)
        throws Exception
{
    // BEGIN: DOM Boilerplate
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(new File("input.xml"));
    XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
    // END: DOM Boilerplate

    // Find and iterate over CHARGE_SUMMARY nodes
    XPathExpression chargeQuery = xpath.compile("/REPORT/REPORT_SUMMARY/CHARGE_SUMMARY");
    NodeList chargeSummaries = (NodeList) chargeQuery.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < chargeSummaries.getLength(); i++) {
        Element chargeSummary = (Element) chargeSummaries.item(i);

        System.out.printf("CHARGE_SUMMARY amount=\"%s\" date=\"%s\" name=\"%s\"%n",
                chargeSummary.getAttribute("amount"),
                chargeSummary.getAttribute("date"),
                chargeSummary.getAttribute("name"));
    }

    // Find and iterate over VALUE nodes
    XPathExpression valueQuery = xpath.compile("/REPORT/REPORT_DETAIL/RESOURCE/CHARGE/VALUE");
    NodeList values = (NodeList) valueQuery.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    String lastResourceName = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.getLength(); i++) {
        Element value = (Element) values.item(i);

        String resourceName = ((Element) value.getParentNode().getParentNode()).getAttribute("name");

        if (!resourceName.equals(lastResourceName)) {
            lastResourceName = resourceName;
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.printf("RESOURCE name=\"%s\" CHARGE name=\"%s\" VALUE amount=\"%s\" datetime=\"%s\"%n",
                resourceName,
                ((Element) value.getParentNode()).getAttribute("name"),
                value.getAttribute("amount"),
                value.getAttribute("datetime"));
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
CHARGE_SUMMARY amount="0.0000" date="2019-01-20" name="CPREMIUM"
CHARGE_SUMMARY amount="-3.8895" date="2019-01-20" name="CUNIMB"

RESOURCE name="GU" CHARGE name="CAB" VALUE amount="3.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T00:30:00+00:00"
RESOURCE name="GU" CHARGE name="CAB" VALUE amount="0.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T01:30:00+00:00"
RESOURCE name="GU" CHARGE name="CPO" VALUE amount="0.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T00:30:00+00:00"
RESOURCE name="GU" CHARGE name="CPO" VALUE amount="0.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T01:30:00+00:00"

RESOURCE name="PU" CHARGE name="COD" VALUE amount="0.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T00:30:00+00:00"
RESOURCE name="PU" CHARGE name="COD" VALUE amount="0.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T01:30:00+00:00"
RESOURCE name="PU" CHARGE name="MOD" VALUE amount="1.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T00:30:00+00:00"
RESOURCE name="PU" CHARGE name="MOD" VALUE amount="2.0000" datetime="2019-01-20T01:30:00+00:00"
```

Comment: Hi Seán, Thank you very much for your time! Great stuff, Hope this helps someone aswell down the line!

Answer (score 0):

Java/DOM is a terribly low-level tool for this job. XSLT has a bit of a learning curve but it ends up being far less code. Here's the solution in XSLT 3.0 (the hardest part was getting the blank lines in the right place):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0" expand-text="yes">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="REPORT_SUMMARY/CHARGE_SUMMARY">
        <xsl:text>CHARGE SUMMARY amount={@amount} date={@date} name={@name}&#xa;</xsl:text>      
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="RESOURCE">
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="RESOURCE/CHARGE/VALUE">
        <xsl:text>RESOURCE name={../../@name} CHARGE name={../@name} VALUE amount={@amount} datetime={@datetime}&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can run this by installing Saxon-HE from SourceForge and either running it direct from the command line:

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar -s:input.xml -xsl:stylesheet.xsl
```

or you can use the API to run it from your Java application.

How it works: the processor starts at the root node looking for a matching template rule. If there isn't one, it goes down a level, and so on recursively. There are three template rules here: one fires when you hit a CHARGE_SUMMARY, one when you hit a VALUE, and these just output the content in a fairly obvious way. The match="RESOURCE" template is there only to output the blank lines between adjacent resources; it outputs a newline (`&#xa;` in XML) and then calls xsl:apply-templates which means "now process the next level down, using the appropriate template rules".

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your reply. I was struggling using DOM, good to know its not the ideal tool for the job. XSLT is quite interesting, I will have to do some extra reading on it!